# How do I switch focus to a new window using Selenium VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, window, selenium-chromedriver, new-window

So, I know how to find the name of the active window

```
currentWindow = bot.Send("GET", "/window_handle")
bot.SwitchToWindowByName currentWindow
```

Is there a way to get the name of the inactive window that I just popped up?

I tried going to console and typing window.name and got ""
Also tried using window.document.name and got "download.phtml", but

```
bot.SwitchToWindowByName download.phtml
```

gave me a Runtime 424 Object Required error.

[Picture of the new window (on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02TjO.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly with

```
bot.SwitchToWindowByTitle "Title"  '<==Make sure it is the actual Title you are using of the Window
```

If it has just popped up you may also try

```
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
```

Comment: How can I switch back to default window after I chose `.SwitchToNextWindow`? I tried using `.SwitchToDefaultWindow` but vba couldn't recognize that command @QHarr.

Comment: You know this one. @MITHU. Switchtodefaultcontent

Comment: That was my first try. I suppose that specific command is for iframe. May be I'm wrong. However, using `.Switchtodefaultcontent` or `SwitchToDefaultWindow` leads to this [error](https://imgur.com/a/ReJUSYW).

Comment: I used this link `https://www.pinterest.com/` then clicked on `log in` and then used `Continue with Google` option. After logging in using google, I used another link to see whether I'm logged in `https://www.google.com/retail/solutions/merchant-center/`. Thanks.

Comment: Afraid I can't test behind login or with vba. I may be able to later today. Once again, you do ask the most interesting questions. I assume that the handle for the prior window is gone so not available.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. You mentioned it few days back.

Comment: I may try an install later today or over next few days. Seems some people can use selenium basic with windows 10 so maybe that is not the problem.

Comment: What is the **Actual Title of The Windows**? I used bot.windows.SwitchToWindowByName(chromeBrowser.Windows.Item(1).Title) with no avail (It actually swithces th windows but returns an error too). I even used the string returned by ``chromeBrowser.Windows.Item(1).Title`` in immediate window