# not able to switch between tabs in chrome using selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I'm finding difficulty in switching between tabs in chrome selenium VBA coding.
I have this website : **http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp**
Where-in i need to input IEC Code : 0906008051
Shipping Bill no :

1. 3929815
2. 3953913
3. 3979509

And then enter the Captcha(this i can do by giving the user 10 seconds of time)
After all this i need to click on "Show Details"(by pressing ctrl) so that it opens in next tab and then copy a specific data from that tab and then close it.
Then a new Shipping bill no is to be taken from the excel sheet and then the process repeats.

I could manage this much of a code :

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub multipletabtest()

Dim bot As WebDriver
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim count As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
'count = 1
'While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

bot.Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp"

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='iec']").SendKeys "0906008051"
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").SendKeys "3929815"
bot.Wait 10000         'Time to enter the captcha

bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter          'Take the value from final result sheet
bot.SwitchToNextWindow

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text
'Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text     'To extract the data
'bot.Window.Close


bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").Clear

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='sno']").SendKeys "3953913"
bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text
'Range("B" & count) = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[.='Used']/ancestor::td[1]").Text


'count = count + 1
'Wend
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

Please look into this and help me out.

Thanks .

Comment: Use the SwitchTo methods. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399698/6241235 and remember to switch back to default if wishing to continue with original window. With early binding you should be offered the list of possible methods on the instantiated webdriver object

Comment: I need help in also clicking the Submit button which is (Ctrl + click on submit button) , that is where i'm finding difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XMLHTTP request:**

I would side step this and avoid as well overhead of using a browser.

Make an initial GET xhr request to `http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/brcIssuedTrade.jsp` and extract the `JSESSION` cookie (you can probably use `.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")` ) then make a subsequent POST xhr request to same url but provide the cookie in the request-headers and in the body ensure you pass the relevant param values.

The param values required are:

```
data = {
  'iec': '0906008051',
  'sno': '3929815',
  'billid': '',
  'brcstat': 'A',
  'captext': 'a7m3p',
  'B1': 'Show Details'
}
```

In VBA, the POST body for the `.send body` would look like:

```
"iec=0906008051&sno=3929815&billid&brcstat=A&captext=a7m3p&B1=Show Details"
```

Where `iec` and `sno` are dynamic and you would concatenate into the body of each request, perhaps in a loop.

```
"iec=" & iec & "&sno=" & sno & "&billid&brcstat=A&captext=" & capText & "=Show Details"
```

If the captcha changes then you can prompt the user to pass in the value for `captext` param and pass that in the body as well.

Don't think any additional headers are required though you might add an user-agent

e.g

```
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent" , "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Learn about xmlhttp (XHR) requests [here](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) or Google (enter the following in the search bar `vba jsession cookie` and hit enter).

The response from the POST request will contain the html within which is your desired table(s).

---

**Selenium:**

If you wish to continue with Selenium, and assuming you have enabled the `Show Details` button with your prior actions, you can use the following attribute = value selector:

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").click
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort, but the selenium code doesn't seem to do the thing i want.
I want it the submit button to open the result in a new tab(child tab) and then extract the value from that, and then close the it.
Later take a new Shipping bill no. from excel file  since the IEC code is same, (plus point is the captcha will remain same), and then again perform ctrl+click function to open a child tab for extraction and so on.

Comment: there isn't a submit button

Comment: There's a "show details" button, that i had been telling as "Submit" button.

Comment: You can do the whole thing without selenium. In terms of with selenium, the above will click the show details button but you need to check your prior steps have enabled the button (post submission of the captcha - and presumably population of required fields)

Comment: Yes my prior steps in selenium have populated all the required fields, i just need to do a ctrl+left mouse so that new tab opens up and then perform the function and then closes it, because this way i need to enter the captcha only once.
ctrl+left mouse shortcut ain't available in selenium ?

Comment: Dim keys As New Selenium.Keys: yourWebElement.SendKeys Keys.Leftcontrol .

Comment: or try yourWebElement.SendKeys Keys.Control, Keys.Left

Comment: Hi sir, i have gone a little better this time, just check the code,i have done,Ctrl +Enter to open a new tab, extract data from it , and closed it.
But the issue is i can't seem to concentrate in the parent window with new Shipping bill no. from excel and then do a ctrl+Enter for new  child window.
Could you please check it out.

Comment: Well done. Side note: you need to be clear what the required actions are. Is it ctrl + left or something else. With respect to the changing windows did you try the switchTo methods I mentioned?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the typo.
No....i'm not getting it. **sobbing in a corner**
I tried but it's just not happening, it has to go to parent window, then input a new "SB no." and now the captcha will be same(plus point), then open the result page in a new tab and so on.....

Comment: I have tried and still not got any proper result, i have just got the result for first "SB no." but for next it doesn't move forward with extraction.

Comment: Sir i have hard coded the whole program, it runs perfect, any help in making it better, because for 1 IEC number i have around 1000 SB.no , so there can be 100 IEC numbers.\

Comment: are you saying that you could have 100*1000 combinations to run? And by hard coded the whole program what do you mean?

Comment: No i meant that for now i have hard coded 
but i'm not getting it to function in a loop since i have large data and i cannot write it in a hard code fashion.

Comment: You should open a new question focusing on the loop problem. Make it clear and concise. Just the relevant code to reproduce the problem you are having. Focus on only one problem. Include any error messages. State the desired behaviour / output (if output generated from single problem being resolved). Show what you have tried in order to solve it and what happened.